# Jetty rejects connection even when there are lot of free threads available in thread pool

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

In production we are using jetty 9.2.9.v20150224 with the following configuration:

```
 new Server(new QueuedThreadPool(200, 5, 30000, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(128)));
```

maxThreads = 200, minThreads = 5, idleTimout = 30000 ms

I tested our application and it was able to handle 200 requests/sec, but few of our clients complain that sometime even with very less load jetty does not accept any new connection and from the log that's what I found *STARTED,5<=18<=200,i=4,q=128*. Which as far as I understand shows there are 18 live threads in the thread pool which is way less then 200, but somehow the new connection is still rejected. Following is the snipped from the log:

```
2021-01-08 00:20:47,813 WARN [qtp1720926658-14444] QueuedThreadPool :     QueuedThreadPool[qtp1720926658]@669341c2{STARTED,5<=18<=200,i=4,q=128}[ReservedThreadExecutor@58a5954d{s=3/4,p=1}] rejected org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DestroyEndPoint@263c181
2021-01-08 00:20:47,813 WARN [qtp1720926658-14444] QueuedThreadPool : QueuedThreadPool[qtp1720926658]@669341c2{STARTED,5<=18<=200,i=3,q=128}[ReservedThreadExecutor@58a5954d{s=3/4,p=1}] rejected org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DestroyEndPoint@431081c5
2021-01-08 00:20:47,813 WARN [qtp1720926658-14445] QueuedThreadPool : QueuedThreadPool[qtp1720926658]@669341c2{STARTED,5<=18<=200,i=2,q=128}[ReservedThreadExecutor@58a5954d{s=3/4,p=1}] rejected org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DestroyEndPoint@3866d8cd
2021-01-08 00:20:47,813 WARN [qtp1720926658-14442] QueuedThreadPool : QueuedThreadPool[qtp1720926658]@669341c2{STARTED,5<=18<=200,i=6,q=126}[ReservedThreadExecutor@58a5954d{s=1/4,p=2}] rejected CEP:SocketChannelEndPoint@4aa81d65{/10.0.1.29:53143<->/10.0.1.28:7777,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=16442/30000}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@32cdb0b1[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@22c521c0{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e02e50f{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}:runFillable:BLOCKING
2021-01-08 00:20:47,829 WARN [qtp1720926658-14442] EatWhatYouKill :
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: CEP:SocketChannelEndPoint@4aa81d65{/10.0.1.29:53143<->/10.0.1.28:7777,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=16442/30000}{io=1/0,kio=1,kro=1}->HttpConnection@32cdb0b1[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@22c521c0{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e02e50f{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}:runFillable:BLOCKING
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.execute(QueuedThreadPool.java:440)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.execute(EatWhatYouKill.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Upgrade Jetty, 9.2.9 is now Deprecated / EOL (End of Life) - https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.php#what-jetty-version  - the thread execution logic has changed tremendously over the past 6 years since 9.2.9 was released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STARTED,5<=18<=200,i=4,q=128` says ...

- `5` is your configured minimum threads
- `<=18<=` is your remaining threads available in the pool
- `200` is your configured max threads
- `i=4` you have 4 idle threads in the pool (eligible for cleanup/removal)
- `q=128` you have 128 tasks/jobs in the queue (this value is too high, it hints at your QTP configuration being insufficient for your load)

Keep in mind that when you experience the rejected tasks/jobs it can be the queue or the pool that rejects them, we don't know which one in Jetty 9.2.x (this information is now available in the logs on Jetty 9.4.x)

This limited view of the QTP in the Jetty 9.2.x series does not show you even half of what's going on internally.

Example: in Jetty 9.4.x+ you see ...

- Configured Minimum
- Configured Maximum
- idle thread count
- active thread count
- busy thread count
- inactive thread count
- reserved thread count
- leased thread count
- utilized count = threads - idle - reserved - leased
- max threads possible = inactive + idle + reserved + leased + utilized
- threads total = idle + reserved + leased + utilized
- busy threads = leased + utilized
- ready threads = idle + reserved
- available = max - busy
- maxAvailable = max - leased
- utilization = utilized / maxAvailable (0.0 means idle, 1.0 means at capacity)

All of which are exposed in JMX as well.

Comment: Hi Joakim, thanks for the answer. What is the highest configuration that I can configure jetty for. Our application runs on a 4 core machine with 8 GB RAM. With this load resources usage does not go more then 30%. For this hardware what will be the right numbers for jetty.

Comment: The configuration you need is based on your application's behaviors first and foremost.   The highest configuration i've seen in use is min=4096, max=32768 (but that was on a azul compute device with over 100 cores and 2TB of memory with an application focused on super quick rest calls with sub 70ms total response time)